# $M^n$ compact, $ f:M^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ smooth $\Rightarrow f$ is not a submersion

Tags: smooth-manifolds

> Let $M^n$ be a smooth, compact manifold. Show that if $f:M\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth, then $f$ is not a submersion.

Let $n=1$, $M=(0,1)$ and $f:x\mapsto x$, then $f_{*_{x}}=1\neq 0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$, so $f$ is a submersion. Isn't this a counter example?

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Is $(0,1)$ compact? ;)

Comment: thanks, @RenanManeliMezabarba, you're totally right. I'll rewrite the question

Comment: In addition to the answers you got, there is a more elementary proof: let $f^1$ be the value of the first coordinate of the map $f$. It is a smooth function on a compact manifold so it attains a supremum somewhere. At that point in particular you have that the Jacobian matrix $Df$ has vanishing first row, and cannot be full rank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, $(0,1)$ is not compact, thus your function is not a counterexample.

Let me just add a sketch of the proof of the tittle of your question.

Recall that submersions are open mappings, while the compactness of $M$ implies that $f$ is closed. Thus, $f(M)$ is a nontrivial clopen of $\mathbb{R}^n$ , hence $f(M)=\mathbb{R}^n$ (the only nontrivial clopens of connected spaces are $\emptyset$ and the whole space).  On the other hand, the compactness of $M$ also implies that $f(M)$ is compact, a contradiction.

Comment: @AguirreK We have that $\emptyset\ne f(M)$ is a clopen, hence the only possibility is $f(M)=\mathbb{R}^n$. In fact, the same reasoning works if you replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a connected smooth manifold $N$.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not clear to me why every submersion is an open map

Comment: Well, I think that by definition it is [a different question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607049/show-that-a-submersion-is-open).

Comment: Roughly speaking, a submersion is like a "local projection", and projections are open.

Comment: Oh, I see, locally open maps are globally open, right? That really helped, thanks!

Comment: I guess yes. You may find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307099/locally-open-maps-are-open-any-reference-and-or-applications) interesting.

Comment: @RenanManeliMeyabarba, in case we substitute $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a connected smooth manifold $N$, we well have that $f(M)$ is open and compact. But can we guarantee that $f(M)$ is closed? I think compactness doesn't imply closure in general, right?

Comment: @AguirreK Compact subspaces of Hausdorff spaces are closed. Does it help?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f:M^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ submersion and $M^n$ compact.

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected implies that $f$ is onto, therefore $f(M^n)=\mathbb{R}^n$.

On the other hand, as $f$ is continuous and $M^n$ compact then $f(M^n)$ is compact but $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not compact.

Contradiction, there is not $f$ a submersion.

Comment: why does the connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^n$ imply that $f$ is onto?

Comment: The only open and closed at a time in a set connected are empty and the total. In this case $f(M^n)$ is closed and open simultaneously.

Comment: @AguirreK" jimbo is using the fact that submersions are open maps (a fact with which you seemed to not be familiar).